# Moving a Wordpress site without access to Admin

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress application has become corrupt in some way. I can no longer log in to the Admin side of Wordpress. However, the public site is available.

I also still have access to the SQL database and the files on the server.

How can I export the site to a new installation given this access?

Alternatively, is there a way to force administrator access by modifying any configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a new WordPress site (locally even) where you know the Administrator password. Once it is set up, open up the database and copy the password for the Administrator from the `wp_users` table and set the value in your old site to be the same. You will be able to log in as the Administrator with the same password you created on your temporary site.

You could also edit your theme's `functions.php` file to update the Admin password. Assuming your Admin user has the default ID of `1`, then add this to the file and request any public page on the site to update the password. It uses the WordPress API [wp_set_password()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) function.

```
wp_set_password( 'new password, 1 );
```